# Randomize string selection

Tags: php, random

Is there a more elegant or more efficient method of randomizing the selection of a string from a list?

```
$case = rand(1,4);
    switch ($case) {
        case 1: $message = "Check this out.";
        break;
        case 2: $message = "Dig this.";
        break;
        case 3: $message = "Listen to this.";
        break;
        case 4: $message = "Try out this.";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: put the message strings in an array, then you can do it with one line of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand)

```
$messages = array(
  "Check this out.",
  "Dig this.",
  "Listen to this.",
  "Try out this."
);

$message = $messages[array_rand($messages)];
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `array_rand()` returns a random array key, not a random array value...